# HTML image (generated by a PHP script) is not displaying in a PDF when converting with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I want to display an image in a PDF file. I am using `wkhtmltopdf` for conversion, like this:

```html
<img src="GetChart.php?&type=PNG&img=bop1&id=vvb0qfkomeqf1nt2hnscraj2q751f25dc72c4ec" alt="The image">
```

I am able to see the image in HTML, but it is not displaying in the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an absolute path to `GetChart.php`.

If it's running on your local machine, try `<img src="http://localhost/GetChart.php?....`

Comment: I give absolute path for this but still i am not able to see my image in pdf

Comment: And you're able to see the image in the HTML version **with the absolute path**? Does the PDF get generated with a broken image, or no PDF at all?